# On publishing some folders are not coming in publish folder

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, publish

Hi I am using VisualStudio 2017 and I had created on project.
Now the issue is when I am trying to publish the code in the folder some of the folder that used to be created in publish folder are not there.

Some folders that are not coming are as follows:

```
App_Data
Plugins
Themes
```

I am publishing as

[image]

Do I need to make any changes?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include all the files into the Project Build.

This can be done by two ways.

1. Manukky include all the required files into the project - Right Click -> Include in Project, Right Click -> Properties -> Build Action -> Folder Name.
2. Add the required files into .csproj/.vbproj file. (This should be under ItemGroup tag.)

**

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="PATHTOTHEFILE" />
```

**